# Open In Place (but only a subset)

Tags: ios

My app can 'view' lots of different file types, but it can only 'edit' a single type.

I have enabled 'open in place' (LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace) so users can use iCloud Drive to 'launch' my app.

Unfortunately all file types are then listed as 'Open In' (my app) - whereas only my app file format should be 'Open In' - all the rest should be 'Copy To'.

I've 'randomly' tweaked the CFBundleDocumentTypes (owners, editors etc.) but to no avail. Anyone know if this is possible - and what the magic combination of plist values is?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? When I add LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace to my Info.plist, the iCloud Drive app opens all documents I tap in my app. Even documents I do not support like Pages or Numbers documents :(

Comment: No solution. The whole iCloud drive thing is a mess. Best avoided until Apple get their act together IMO.

Comment: I guess you should let them now then and file a radar on bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 10, setting the LSHandlerRank to anything but "Owner" (ie. to "Alternate") should have this effect. You'll still get files that are open-in-place'able, only the UI changes.